# Protocol or technique for assigning IP addresses to an un-addressed device

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-protocols

I'm working on a product which is a "black box" device that will be connected to a client's network.  I am looking for a method of assigning a static IP address to the device (or configuring it to use DHCP, which will likely be the default).  There is no physical user interface, no screens or buttons to enter such information on the device itself.  It will have a web-based interface, but to use that it will need to obtain an IP address first and the user will need to know what that address is.

I have used a number of devices similar to this that come with utility that you run on a PC which detects the device on the network and allows you to view and change its IP configuration.  This is what I would like to do, but I'm not sure which protocols to use or how to go about it.  I picture the utility broadcasting a "who's there?" packet over the network and my black box device responding with an "I'm here" packet.  The utility would then theoretically know the device's MAC address and could communicate further by requesting its current IP configuration and sending it new configuration if needed.

Side note: The black box will be running some flavor of Linux and the utility should run on Windows.

EDIT: Typically we will ship one of these black boxes to a customer, they will unpack it and plug it into their network.  Outside of communicating with it over the network there is no way to configure the black box; there is no monitor and keyboard, no user interface panel of any kind, no means of editing any configuration files in the Linux file system.  The utility we provide the customer must be easy to use.  They should be able to run the utility, see the device in a list of detected black boxes, and select the device to view or modify its configuration.  These users are not system admins, I do not expect them to be able to connect to the black box via SSH and edit configuration files.

I welcome suggestions on approaches to take or protocols to use to accomplish my goal.  If you have experience doing what I am trying to do please outline what you did (or how you would do it now).

Thanks!

Comment: How many machines? Why not DHCP - work already done? If static IP requires and then just configure the /etc/hosts (or the moral windows equilivant)

Comment: DHCP would be fine, but the user still needs to figure out what the IP address is in order to open the web interface.  Also, this product will be placed in manufacturing environments where static IP addresses are fairly common and DHCP servers don't always exist (in my experience anyway).

Comment: If you want web interfaces just configure each machine with a static IP address - it takes 5/10 mins per machines